# sizeWithFont memory leak in iphone

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I have this code:

```
[[data objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]]
                     sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]  
                     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(276.0, 1000.0)  
                     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

data is a NSDictionary.

It is said this code has 16 bytes leak, but I cant find it.

Help

Comment: You need to provide more detail. All you have there is an access to something in a collection class, you need to show how the thing is allocated, what its scope is, etc. Have you tried using the Leaks tool available under Instruments?

Answer (score 2):

What type does the NSDictionary return?

```
[[data objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]]
```

Break the statement up to better figure out where the leak may be:

```
NSString *s = [[data objectForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]];
CGSize size = [s sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]
            constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(276.0, 000.0)
                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you leak only one 16byte block for the entire life of your app?  Or are you leaking 16 bytes every time through a loop?

If it is 16 bytes only, I am not sure if I'd worry too much about it.  I'm saying that given that some of the caching I have seen done by the OS tends to look like leaking.